# Updated row format not showing?

Tags: mysql

I updated row format with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    drop column id,
    add primary key(column_1, column_2),
    ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED,
    ALGORITHM=INPLACE,
    LOCK=EXCLUSIVE;
```

Ignore the drop column and add primary key clauses, it's a big table and I wanted to do that in 1 alter table...

In any case, when it completed I checked the results with:

`SHOW TABLE STATUS IN my_db;`

Oddly enough, in the given results under the row_format column, it shows Compact. However in the Create_options column it says row_format=COMPRESSED.

Below query shows that the row format is still showing Compact.

```
SELECT NAME, ROW_FORMAT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES;
```

My question is why did the row format not update? What does it mean that the create options now says `row_format=COMPRESSED` even though the row format on the table shows `Compact`?

Note: I updated row format to compressed just to see if it would improve performance. There are two int(11) columns and one decimal(18,6). Now that I think about it, does row_format=compressed not apply for a table without strings?

Comment: In Workbench you can also "view" the Create Table statement to make sure it's (data types and keys) what you think it is

Comment: The create table statement shows the `ROW_FORMAT=Compressed` but I'm more concerned why the other system tables do not show this

Comment: It sounds like it doesn't update the metadata tables immediately. InnoDB is notorious for being lazy like this.

Comment: Read about [information_schema_stats_expiry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry) and try setting this option to 0. The table's ROW_FORMAT is not listed as one of the stats that needs to be refreshed, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is affected.

Comment: Please show us the output from both the SHOW and the SELECT.  Also, what version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

> does row_format=compressed not apply for a table without strings

There are other things in the row -- lengths, offsets, etc.

Each `INT` takes 4 bytes; that `DECIMAL` takes 9.  That's 17 bytes, but I would expect Avg_row_length to be more than 40 due to the overhead.  And, as you may have found out, Compression would not help much.

There are smaller `INTs` and that `DECIMAL` seems excessively big.  Consider whether a 4-byte `FLOAT` (about 7 *signifigant* digits) would suffice.

If you wish to tell us what the numbers represent, I may have further tips for saving space.

Even with strings, `row_format=COMPRESSED` rare gets more than 2:1 compression.